# Can I run apps on iPhone without paying to be a developer?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am new to ios development.

I am using Xcode 6.4 and iOS 8.4.1, when I'm trying to run my app on
my device I get this message from xcode:

> No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair)
>   matching the team ID “(null)” were found.
>
> Xcode can attempt to fix this issue.

And when clicking "Fix issue" it suggesting me to enrol Apple's dev program. I would rather not be a paid developer - is that the only way forward?

Comment: You need to make your apps in Xcode 7 to run on your iDevice without any developer account. You need to sign in with your Apple ID. For more details visit the Xcode 7 site. It's in beta 6 now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your apps in Xcode 7 to run on your iDevice without any developer program. You need to sign in with your Apple ID. For more details visit the Xcode 7 site. It's in beta 6 now.

https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

If you need Xcode 6 or lower, paying the fee is the only alternative.